# Measure of clumpiness or cluster of 1D continuous data over a given range

Tags: distributions, clustering, entropy

I'm looking for a measure of how clustered (or converse empty) data is over a range (e.g. `[0,1]` in this case). The first obvious metric to use would be entropy (or rather an estimator for continuous distributions), however this weights the density of points too much.

The second obvious route would be to look at how 'empty' the space is. So a discrete version would be to split the data into `N` bins and normalise the non-zero count (i.e. in numpy you might implement it as `np.count_nonzero(np.histogram(data, range=(0,1), bins=N)[0])/N`). However, this feels too dependant on the number of bins chosen `N`.

Below is a plot of the data I'm working with. The x-axis represents varying a model parameter, the y-axis is what I'm trying to obtain this measure for. For any x, there are 1000 points. The top graph is coloured by entropy of the y points for the given x.

[image]

On the bottom we see the left most cluster is very high for entropy (blue line). Using 100 bins feels about right (orange lne) compared to 1000 bins (green line). However, this feels extremely arbitrarily.

So **is there a metric for non-zero count of continuous data which is not dependent on the bin number?** If the answer is for n-dimensions even better, but 1D would be enough.

Thank you so much!

Comment: is there any reason why you are discarding the: variance, standard deviation, mad, interquartile range, and Gini concentration index, among the many other measures of spread?

Comment: Sorry I thought they were too obviously inappropriate for this problem. Given they're all measured around a single centre. This doesn't care about the multimodal nature of the distribution.

Comment: By bins you mean equal-width bins, subranges?

Comment: Think maybe of some "clustering tendency measure", such as Hopkins statistic. It is around 0.5 if the structure is random noise, close to 1 if there are good clusters, and close to 0 if the points are regular grid.

Comment: borrowing from @ttnphns' last comment and since you do not know how many clusters are there and to which cluster each value belongs, would a clustering-based measure be satisfactory for you?